# How do I square a logarithm?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How do I square $\log_2(3)$. Does it become $2\log_2(3)$ ?

Answer (score 54):

No. $(\log_2(3))^2$ can't be simplified.

However, $\log_2(3^2)=2\log_2(3)$.

Comment: Well, one does have $(\log_2(3))^2=\log_2(3^{\log_2(3)})$, but I'm not sure whether you can call that a simplification.

Answer (score 21):

No, it doesn't. Logarithms follow this rule:
$$
\log_b (a^c) = c\log_b a,
$$
while your statement says that
$$
(\log_b a)^c=c\log_b a,$$
which is basically saying the same as $x^y=yx$.

Answer (score 9):

$\log_2(3) \approx 1.58496$ as you can easily verify.

$(\log_2(3))^2 \approx (1.58496)^2 \approx 2.51211$.

$2 \log_2(3) \approx 2 \cdot 1.58496 \approx 3.16992$.

$2^{\log_2(3)} = 3$.

Do any of those appear to be equal?

(Whenever you are wondering whether some general algebraic relationship holds, it's a good idea to first try some simple numerical examples to see if it is even possible.)

Actually, the only way that $(\log_2(3))^2 = 2 \log_2(3)$ could hold is if $\log_2(3)$ were equal to 2 or 0.  That is clearly false since $2^2 = 4 \ne 3$ and $2^0 = 1 \ne 3$.

Comment: I am an engineer, and I would say that 3rd and 4rt are equal, indeed. :P

Comment: You: _Actually, the only way that $(\log_2(3))^2 = 2 \log_2(3)$ could hold is if $\log_2(3)$ were equal to 2._ Maybe that should be "2 or 0" (the solutions to $x^2=2x$). For example, $(\log_2(1))^2 = 2 \log_2(1)$.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Thanks, fixed,

Answer (score 7):

No.The best you can do is $$(\log_2 3)^2=\log_2 3\cdot \log_2 3=\log_2 (3^{\log_2 3})$$

Comment: log3 on base 2 cant be 2^ log 3 on base 2?

Answer (score 3):

Agreeing with the rest of the answers here, you cannot simplify any further.  You could, however, do a change of base with the logs and put them in base $10$.  We have the formula
$$\log_bx=\frac{\log_ax}{\log_ab}$$where $a$ can be any base you want.  Most common base is $10$.  So we have,
$$(\log_23)^2=\left(\frac{\log_{10}3}{\log_{10}2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\log3}{\log2}\right)^2=\frac{\log^23}{\log^22}$$

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald To make a calculator do it?

Comment: @KSmarts In which world does this relate to the question asked?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray}
(\log_{2}(3))^{2} &=& (\log_{2}(3))(\log_{2}(3)) \\
                  &=& \log_{2}(3^{\log_{2}(3)})
\end{eqnarray}
That's as simple as it gets!

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that
$$
(\log_{2}(3))^{2} = 2^{\log_2 (\log_{2}(3))^{2}} = 2^{2 \log_2 (\log_{2}(3))}
$$

The advantage of writing it like this is that it can be generalized to higher powers of the logarithm, e.g.
$$
\ln(x)^3 = e^{3\ln(\ln(x))}
$$
And for arbitrary powers of the logarithm we get
$$
\ln(x)^q = \prod_{i=1}^q \ln(x)  = e^{q\ln(\ln(x))}
$$